# Should we Put Coupon Pages into sitemap because they do have a faster expiry rate?

Tags: web-crawlers, sitemap, search-engine-indexing, xml-sitemap

Is it a good practice to keep coupons/ voucher pages into a sitemap. because they do have a faster expiry rate.

Case:

We are updating our sitemap once in 24 hours so, will it be a good practice to keep the coupon pages into the sitemap. Because if they get expire but, not updated into the sitemap will that be an issue?

Will adding them cause an effect on the crawling budget due to the expiration of the page into 404.

Answer (score 1):

Since you do have coupon pages (in general: pages), you should add them to your sitemap. There is an option to indicate how often your page gets updated via  the `<changefreq>` but keep in mind it is often not taken into account by Google.

To avoid returning 404 errors to googlebot consider implementing a way to return 410 status instead (a resource used to exist but now is `gone`). This way you will signal that a page is gone in a more meaningful way instead of returning a 404 error.

When it comes to crawling budget, this case will not affect it. Crawling budget is affected by how fast your server responds, the SEO of your page, the loading time of your page etc. When it comes to non technical aspects, crawling budget is also affected by your site's popularity, your content quality, the number of visitors etc.

Your case, a temporary page that soon-ish ceases to exist is not one of the factors that affect crawling budget. You can read more about it [in this official google webmaster post](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2017/01/what-crawl-budget-means-for-googlebot.html).

Comment: And what are the chances that the product/ coupon pages will start competing with the landing/category pages? 

For Example:
(Category Word)

Best Gaming Laptops in New Zeland 

Product Page

Buy Asus 17 Inch | Best Gaming Laptop 2018 | NZ Product

Comment: @P082 use canonical urls to indicate which page should get the juice.

Comment: This logic will create an issue. Because of the no. of landing pages are limited and the coupon are in like multiple x's so, I think logic will fail